# SharePoint.dll reference error in .Net Frameworks 3.0

Tags: sharepoint-server, assembly-references

Before the question, In my PC develop environment like this.

SharePoint 2016, SQL Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Visual Studio 2015.

I made a SharePoint Analysis Winform application under .Net Frameworks 4.5

and added SharePoint.dll(version 16.0.0.0) reference.

It works well, and then I try to make same application under .Net Frameworks 3.0

I built a code, and tried to debugging, message like this

**Can not determine default reference "Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0..." 
because it is dependent on version 4.0.0, which is higher than version 2.0 in
the current target framework.**

So I guess I should change that SharePoint.dll. Is it right?

And 1 more question, If I made that program, it is possible to run my PC??

Because My PC`s SharePoint version is 2016....

Please somebody help me....

P.S. I translated my Error message to english.. so if you cannot understand it,

comment me...